# Webcontent ( control panel ) in Liferay And normal user?

Tags: permissions, content-management-system, liferay, web-content, control-panel

Is there any feature that can show list of webcontent that one user had submited and they have permission to edit owner entry only emoticon
I have trouble with permission on webcontent.
I try to grant Creator permission to add new entry (on asset publisher) ,the [Add New] button appear, Creator can click on it, but there is no [Submit] button to submit entry (?) until i grant Creator permission to update entry, but if I grant Creator permission to update, he can also edit entry which is not his owner